# Authorize.net Transaction ID Changes

Tags: authorize.net, magento-1.5

I have received below message from Authorize.net team.
 In October of this year, due to system updates, it will be possible to receive Authorize.Net IDs (Transaction ID, Batch ID, etc.) that are not in sequential order.

Currently, if you receive a Transaction ID of "1000," you could expect that the next Transaction ID would not be less than 1000. However, after the updates, it will be possible to receive a Transaction ID less than the one you previously received.

If your system has any functionality that expects Authorize.Net-generated IDs to be sequential, please update it immediately so that you will not see any disruptions to your solution.

Additionally, please make sure that your solution does not restrict any Authorize.Net ID field to 10 characters. If you are required to define a character limit when storing any of our IDs, the limit should be no less than 20 characters.

What does this message mean and how can I make sure if things will work fine in my Magento store after these changes and what changes do I need to make to all go smooth?

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore this because magento system using 100 character limit and it's varchar type with out auto increment

Comment: try and enhance your answer if you can, giving a bit more details. it's always more appreciated than a one-liner

Answer (score 0):

Magento doesn't expect external transaction IDs to be sequential.

Regarding storage, Magento uses long varchar fields to store transaction IDs eg. in `sales_flat_order_payment` table:

```
`last_trans_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Last Trans Id',
```

Or in `sales_payment_transaction` table:

```
txn_id` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Txn Id',
`parent_txn_id` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Parent Txn Id',
```

It looks you should be good, nothing to do.